# Playing with my Apple Health Data but the csv is harder to wrangle than I have encountered

Tags: pandas, time, time-series

My pandas dataframe comes out as:

```
                                      BURNED CALORIES      
Date     00 - 01 01 - 02 02 - 03 .... 23 - 24
1/13/19  17.6    11.53   3.24         28.6
1/14/19  1.5     1.46    2.41         27.44
```

The top row is the hourly breakdown but the only column is Burned Calories over the 23-24 hour column. I feel as though I need to pivot it but I can't pull the Date column as an actual column. Any suggestions? Ideally, I would like to create a timeseries and play with hourly data.

This is what I would like to get to:

Date Hour Burned Calories

Thank you!!

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBrLx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had to set the header to 1

Then run the melt operation and it was a success. Thank you again!

Now to convert my 23 - 24 to hours but I think I will split by delimiter then convert to time.

```
df2=burnedcalories2018.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='variable') df2.rename(columns={'variable':'hours', 'value':'calories burned'}, inplace=True) df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']) df2.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, is that what you're looking for?

```
df2=df.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='variable')
df2.rename(columns={'variable':'hours', 'value':'calories burned'}, inplace=True)
df2
```

```
    Date    hours   calories burned
0   1/13/19 00-01   17.6
1   1/14/19 00-01   1.5
2   1/13/19 01-02   11.53
3   1/14/19 01-02   1.46
4   1/13/19 02-03   3.24
5   1/14/19 02-03   2.41
6   1/13/19 23-24   28.6
7   1/14/19 23-24   27.44
```

Comment: I can make that work! The hours are the times, let me give that a whirl.

Comment: That is close. Part of the problem is "Date" is the index so I don't know how to manipulate it. The error I just got was:           Keyerror: "Date"

Comment: 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: you can reindex() your df and 'date' will become another column.

Answer (score 1):

'''df2=burnedcalories2018.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='variable')
df2.rename(columns={'variable':'hours', 'value':'calories burned'}, inplace=True)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)'''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).